# This function takes 2 arguments but 1 argument was supplied

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node

I'm working on a Substrate project, and I have the following storage definition:

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn bids)]
pub(super) type Bids<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<
    _,
    Twox64Concat,
    Key<T>,
    Twox64Concat,
    HashId<T>,
    (Key<T>, BalanceOf<T>),
    OptionQuery,
>;
```

I'm trying to retrieve all items associated with a specific auction key using the Bids storage. Here's the code I'm using:

```
let auction_key: Key<T> = ...; // Set the auction key appropriately

let bid_history: = Bids::<T>::get(&auction_key);
```

> This function takes 2 arguments but 1 argument was supplied

It seems that the get function of Bids requires two arguments instead of one. I'm looking for a way to retrieve all items related to the auction_key. How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `iter_prefix_values` (see [Rust Docs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/trait.StorageDoubleMap.html#tymethod.iter_prefix_values)), to iterates over values that share the first key.

See an example in [this test](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/support/src/storage/types/double_map.rs#L959) in the FRAME support pallet:

```rs
type A = StorageDoubleMap<Prefix, Blake2_128Concat, u16, Twox64Concat, u8, u32, OptionQuery>;
A::insert(3, 30, 11);
A::insert(3, 31, 12);

assert_eq!(A::iter_prefix_values(3).collect::<Vec<_>>(), vec![12, 11]);
```